# Find a series with recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to write a **recursive** function that gets an array by pointer and its size, and returns the length of the longest series of identical adjacent numbers in the array (assume that there is a series),

For example:

```
array: {1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 7 8} 
returns-->: 4
```

but I don't know what's wrong with my function; I think I got it all wrong.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int LongestSeries(int* arr, int size, int* count, int* maxcount);


int main()
{
    int i, size, *arr, count=0, maxcount=0;

    // allocation an array (unknow size)
    {
        printf("Enter Size of the Array-->:");
        scanf("%d", &size);

        arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        if (arr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error!!");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter Numbers for the Array:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter a Number-->:");
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf(" %d \n", LongestSeries(arr, size, count, maxcount));

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}


int LongestSeries(int* arr, int size, int* count, int* maxcount)
{
    if (arr[size-1] == arr[size-2])
        count++;
    if (maxcount<count)
        maxcount = count;

    LongestSeries(arr, size - 1, count, maxcount);

    if (*arr==arr[0])
        return maxcount;
}
```

Comment: We are not here to write your code. Please learn to use your debugger

Comment: So, you want to find the longest sequence of repeated numbers, not the longest sequence of consecutive numbers? Both of these would be 4 in your example.

Comment: you are comparing `maxcount < count` when both are pointers, you probably want to compare their values instead

Answer (score 0):

There're some problems in your code:

1 - The function `LongestSeries` expects a pointer on `count` and `maxcount` arguments but you passed the variable's values instead. You need to change the function call to send the address reference, like this: `printf(" %d \n", LongestSeries(arr, size, &count, &maxcount));`

2 - Your recursion termination condition is placed below the recursion call, causing the recursion never ending. You need to place it above the recursion call, preferably be the first statement in your recursive function.

3 - Since your `count` and `maxcount` arguments are pointers, you must use the dereference operator to work with the values instead its addresses:

from this:

```
if (arr[size-1] == arr[size-2])
        count++;
    if (maxcount<count)
        maxcount = count;
```

to this:

```
if (arr[size-1] == arr[size-2])
        ++*count;
    if (*maxcount < *count)
        *maxcount = *count;
```

4 - The same applies in your return statement: you're returing the pointer, but your function expects an int to be returned, so:

from this:

```
if (*arr==arr[0])
        return maxcount;
```

to this:

```
if (*arr==arr[0])
        return *maxcount;
```

5 - Since you need the longest series, your `count` variable needs to start at `1`, not `0`, since the lowest possible series in a number sequence is 1, and not 0.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you try your solution? Are you sure that `*++count` is what you want? And what about OP code passing the `int`s `count` and `maxcount` into the function, which is expecting pointers to `int`; and why is OP passing pointers in the first place. So many problems with OP code....

Comment: Under what circumstance would `*arr==arr[0]` be false? The only one I can think of involves NaNs, but in this case `arr` is an array of `int`. Just sayin' In most cases, it's not worth the trouble to try to "fix" code like this: It's not what SO is designed for, and it's not going to help either the OP (who needs to learn how to learn) nor future readers.

Comment: @DavidBowling Sorry, my mistake. I changed the code example. I'm not too versed in C, just trying to help. Yes, I tested the code and worked as expected.

Comment: I had not noticed at first, but I see now that you had already mentioned that OP was passing `int`s instead of pointers. Still, even with your corrections, posted code will not work. The more fundamental problem, as I see it, is that OP is misunderstanding recursion.

Comment: @rici Yes, this condition is wrong, if he is substracting the size at each recursive call, it might check the size as a termination condition.

Comment: Hmmm. I tested it, and it did not work. Note that `*arr==arr[0]` is always true.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes, I agree too. Maybe changing the condition to `if (size < 2)`, is ugly but works.

Comment: I compiled the [code you posted](https://pastebin.com/6cQZtbLb), and received a warning: "control reaches end of non-void function". When I ran the code, the result was 5 for OP's example. I have added an answer of my own to show something I would consider more in the spirit of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with the posted code, as pointed out by [@MarcLaurent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44221749/6879826). But fundamentally, the approach seems flawed. The point of writing recursive functions is not to make things difficult, but to make things simple. Problems that lend themselves to recursion can be broken down into smaller subproblems.

For the problem at hand, finding the length of the longest sequence of repeated numbers in an array, one recursive approach would acknowledge that this length is either the length of the initial sequence of repeated numbers, or the length of the longest sequence of repeated numbers in the remainder of the array. In code, this might look like:

```
size_t longest_seq(size_t sz, int *a)
{
    if (sz == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    size_t count = init_seq(sz, a);
    return MAX(count, longest_seq(sz - count, a + count));
}
```

Here, if the array contains no elements (the base case), `0` is returned. Otherwise, the larger of the length of the initial sequence, or the longest sequence in the remainder of the array is returned. `MAX` is a macro here, easily defined, and we have only to write a function that finds the length of the initial sequence. This can also be recursive, though it need not be.

A recursive function that finds the length of the initial sequence could look like:

```
size_t init_seq(size_t sz, int *a)
{
    if (sz == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + ((sz > 1 && a[0] == a[1]) ? init_seq(sz - 1, a + 1) : 0);
}
```

Here, if the array contains no elements (the base case), then the length is obviously `0`, otherwise the return value is `1` added to the length of the initial sequence of the remainder of the array (if there is a next element, and that element is the same as the first element), or `0`.

By breaking the problem down in this way, the solution is simple and easy to understand. Here is a full program implementing the above ideas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(X, Y) (X) > (Y) ? (X) : (Y)

size_t longest_seq(size_t, int *);
size_t init_seq(size_t, int *);

int main(void)
{
    size_t arr_sz;
    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%zu", &arr_sz);

    int arr[arr_sz];

    printf("Enter array values:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("Longest sequence of repeats: %zu\n", longest_seq(arr_sz, arr));

    return 0;
}

size_t longest_seq(size_t sz, int *a)
{
    if (sz == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    size_t count = init_seq(sz, a);
    return MAX(count, longest_seq(sz - count, a + count));
}

size_t init_seq(size_t sz, int *a)
{
    if (sz == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + ((sz > 1 && a[0] == a[1]) ? init_seq(sz - 1, a + 1) : 0);
}
```

Sample program interaction:

```
Enter number of elements: 12
Enter array values:
1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 7 8
Longest sequence of repeats: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int LongestSeries(int* arr, int size, int count, int maxcount){
    if(size == 0)
        return maxcount < count ? count : maxcount;

    if(count == 0){
        return LongestSeries(arr + 1, size - 1, 1, maxcount);
    } else {
        if(arr[-1] == *arr){
            return LongestSeries(arr + 1, size - 1, count + 1, maxcount);
        } else {
            if(count > maxcount)
                maxcount = count;
            return LongestSeries(arr + 1, size - 1, 1, maxcount);
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    printf("%d\n", LongestSeries(arr, size, 0, 0));
}
```

---

reduce code:

```
int LongestSeries(int* arr, int size, int count, int maxcount){
    if(size == 0)
        return maxcount < count ? count : maxcount;

    if(count == 0 || arr[-1] != *arr){
        if(count > maxcount)
            maxcount = count;
        return LongestSeries(arr + 1, size - 1, 1, maxcount);
    }
    return LongestSeries(arr + 1, size - 1, count + 1, maxcount);
}
```